# Derivative with integral inequality proof

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

let $f(x)$ be second derivative on $[0,1]$,and $$f''(x)\ge 0,f'(x)<0,\forall x\in[0,1], f(0)=0,f(1)=-1$$

show that
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\dfrac{f'^2(x)+1}{|f(x)|}}dx\le 2\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Well, at least I don't think your hint works. Obviously, when $f=-x$, the functional gets its maximum, but $\int_0 ^1 1/|x| dx = \infty$.  The point is to show, why the minimizer is a linear function.

Comment: Sorry, I should say, the maximizer.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not well-posed.

Let $f(x)=x^{10}-2x$,satisfying $$f''(x) \ge 0, \forall x \in [0,1],f(0)=0,f(1)=-1$$but$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\dfrac{f'^2(x)+1}{|f(x)|}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\dfrac{(10x^9-2)^2+1}{|x^{10}-2|}}dx=3.28097>2\sqrt2$$

Actually the supremum of the functional is $\infty$.

Comment: Hello,you have somewrong, I think $f(x)=x^{10}-2x$,but then you have true,if $f(x)$ add monotone decreasing,maybe is true

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. The calculation is actually done by taking $f(x)=x^{10}-2x$, so it works.